# Settings/Displays multi-monitor: turning off a display doesn't work on Juno/Intel Haswell

Tags: settings

On Juno, Intel Haswell notebook with external monitor, trying to turn off a monitor doesn't actually work. When I use

Settings -> Displays -> any_monitor -> Use This Display -> OFF

the monitor is still on.

xrandr:
eDP-1 connected (built-in)
DP-1 connected (external monitor)

Running
xrandr --output any_output --off

does work.

Tried booting into stock 18.10 and the Settings/Displays app was able to set Single Display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bug waiting for fix: [#131](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-display/issues/131)

you can try 'super + p' combo to switch.

on my side notebook with 1 intel gpu the combo works (can disable internal display), on notebook with intel + nvidia gpu not work(without external display plugin, and super+p makes it even more worse, the desktop completely unusable.)